# VBA Code to import Multiple column fron one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to import a few columns from one excel spreadsheet to another. Below is the code that I have found on this forum which is working fine. The only problem I am facing is it is importing only one column.

Can someone please guide how I can edit the code so that I can importing multiple columns?

```
Importing single Column
Sub CopyColumnToWorkbook()
Dim sourceColumn As Range, targetColumn As Range

Set sourceColumn = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Worksheets("2017"). Columns(“A”)
Set targetColumn = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Worksheets("Field WH Projections").Columns(“A”)

sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could use string letters as column "Numbers" (i.e. `Columns("A") = Columns(1)`. I learn something even from a complete newbie post! I'll give this a bump for that reason. So technically all you needed was to change your code to be "A:C" or however many you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updating Based On OP Requirement for Unconnected Columns**

```
Sub ColumnCopy()
Dim Source_Sheet As Worksheet, Target_Sheet As Worksheet
Dim CLM As Integer, LastColumn As Integer

Set Source_Sheet = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Worksheets("2017")
Set Target_Sheet = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Worksheets("Field WH Projections")

LastColumn = Source_Sheet.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

For CLM = 1 To LastColumn

'Columns 1 or (A)...  2 (B).... F and H.
If CLM = 1 Or CLM = 2 Or CLM = 6 Or CLM = 8 Then

Source_Sheet.Columns(CLM).Copy Destination:=Target_Sheet.Columns(CLM)

End If

Next CLM

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah I can use the column ("A:C" ) but my columns are not sequential (I.e. "A,B,F,H") that I am look to import

Comment: Updated. Obviously, you'd have to change around the numbers if you ever change columns. Normally I might do some kind of find function like this for my work, but hopefully this gets you an understanding of range and if statements.

Comment: its giving me that script out of range error for some reason I even tried renaming the file to check if that was causing the error. did it run on your side ?